# как сделать редирект joomla .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Помогите почему второй редирект работает, а первый нет, обратился к технической поддержки хостинга и они ответили, что для ссылки `/component/content/?view=featured` происходит конфликт с другими правилами редиректа указанными в файле `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# не работает
Redirect 301 /component/content/?view=featured http://airtech.kz/

# работает
Redirect 301 /40-bez-kategorii/285-glavnaya http://airtech.kz/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
Redirect 301 /component/content/?view=featured http://airtech.kz/
```

на

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/component\/content\/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bview=featured\b [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://airtech.kz/? [R=301,L]
```

P.S. Техподдержке объявите выговор. Конфликта тут нет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Техподдержка наверное имела ввиду что строки.

```
# не работает
Redirect 301 /component/content/?view=featured http://airtech.kz/

# работает
Redirect 301 /40-bez-kategorii/285-glavnaya http://airtech.kz/
```

Конфликтуют в плане того, что работа перой строки, затирается выполнением соедующей строки так, как ни в первой ни во второй строке не указан параметр `[L]`
в конце строк, который прерывает обработку дальнейших строк если текущая строка сработала.

Comment: то есть вы хотите сказать что мне нужно поставить `[L]` во второй строке тоже?
Как в первой строке так и во второй? в конце верно и получиться это все вот так
`Redirect 301 /40-bez-kategorii/285-glavnaya http://airtech.kz/ [L]`

Comment: Я правильно говорю?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l вот документация про флаг L от слова Last последний. Вам правильнее использовать RewriteRule а не Redirect

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, Redirect является плохо настраиваемым и наверное не поддерживает флаг L, поэтому у вас срабатывает только второе правило Redirect, добавите третье правило Redirect и срабатывать будет только оно.

Comment: Вы можете проверить опытным путем, закомментив вторую строчку и проверить работает ли первая, при проверках не забудьте очистить кешь браузера ибо 301 редиректы браузер запоминает и потом не смотрит на то что на самом деле сервер ему не давал указания делать редирект.

Comment: Нужно просто дать понять что они отличаются от друг друга, тогда будут работать два редиректа, а на данные момен это выглядит типа Echo "Hello World"; Echo "Hello World 1";  т.е всега будет срабатывать последний. А если они будут различаться, т.е сделать Rewrite Rule, или указать с какого именно параметра будет начинаться строка, тогда будет ясно что это две разные строки, и редирект заработает в обоих случаях.

Comment: Спасибо всем огромное за такое объяснение в первом случае /component/content/?view=featured я сделал то что мне писал Visman а вторую строку я оставил без изменения надеюсь я все правильно сделал? и не нарушил то что идет ниже моих редиректов?